# How to calculate delay in 8051 micro controller

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

I'm studying for my finals in 8051 micro controller course and I don't understand something and I need your help with figuring it out.

I understand that the 8051 can have an Internal oscillator and an External oscillator.

From what I've read, the Internal oscillator is set (as default) to 2 MHz and the External oscillator can have 4 types: Crystal, Capacitor, Resistor-Capacitor (RC) and CMOS clock.

My question is about the initializing System clock (to external Crystal oscillator) and how to calculate the delay of 1 ms (to let the Crystal oscillator settel).

When I read the following code (for the initialization of the system clock) I don't understand how the line `DJNZ ACC, $` gives me 512 μs.

I think I know how to calculate the delay time with the formula:

but I get a delay of 278 μs and not a delay of 513 μs.

My delay formula calculation - with the 22.1184 MHz

[image: My delay formula calculation - with the 22.1184 MHz]

My delay formula calculation - with the 12 MHz

[image: my delay formula calculation - with the 12 MHz]

but when I change the `F_SysClk` to 12 MHz. Everything works out and I get the 513 μs. But I don't get why do I need to use the 12 MHz and not the 22.1184 MHz.

Can you please explain to me why do I use the 12 MHz?

This is the image from my textbook that I having trouble with

[image: this is the image from my textbook that I having trouble with]

Comment: kindly use proper spelling next time. I've fixed it for you. And copy the code form your textbook if possible instead of posting an image of it

Comment: What type of crystal do you have? 12 MHz or 22.1184 MHz?

Comment: I use a 22.1184 MHz crystal oscillator (as seen in the last image of my post).

Comment: sorry. the result of the second equation (with the 12 MHz) is: 513 us and not 513810 us.